# Zoom not working in a map inside scrollview in android

Tags: android

**What i am doing**::

- I am using mapquest widget and api for maps
- I am haveing the mapwidget inside the scrollview
- I am able to click the map markers in the map also

**What is happening**::

- I am not able to to zoom the map,
- I can see zoom buttons clickit also but it wont zoom

**code**::

***MyFragment.java***

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

    protected MapView map;
    AnnotationView annotation;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container,false);
        map = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        map.getController().setZoom(10);
        map.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(12.918609,77.668912));
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        // initialize the annotation to be shown later 
        annotation = new AnnotationView(map);

        //addPolyOverlay();
        // addLineOverlay();

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();


        addPoiOverlay();
    }


    // add an itemized overlay to map 
    private void addPoiOverlay() {

        // use a custom POI marker by referencing the bitmap file directly,
        // using the filename as the resource ID 
        Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.distance_icon_large);
        final DefaultItemizedOverlay poiOverlay = new DefaultItemizedOverlay(icon);

        // set GeoPoints and title/snippet to be used in the annotation view 
        OverlayItem poi1 = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint (12.918609,77.668912), "Denver, Colorado", "MapQuest Headquarters");
        poiOverlay.addItem(poi1);
        OverlayItem poi2 = new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint (12.956868,77.701148), "Palo Alto, California", "AOL Offices");
        poiOverlay.addItem(poi2);

        // add a tap listener for the POI overlay 
        poiOverlay.setTapListener(new ItemizedOverlay.OverlayTapListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTap(GeoPoint pt, MapView mapView) {
                // when tapped, show the annotation for the overlayItem 
                int lastTouchedIndex = poiOverlay.getLastFocusedIndex();
                if(lastTouchedIndex>-1){
                    OverlayItem tapped = poiOverlay.getItem(lastTouchedIndex);
                    annotation.showAnnotationView(tapped);
                }
            }
        });



        map.getOverlays().add(poiOverlay);
    }

}
```

**fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.mapquest.android.maps.MapView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="700dp"
                android:apiKey="My-Key"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="5dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override the touchlistener in the scrollview and then forward those events to the mapview if appropriate. The problem is that the scrollview is taking over the touch listener without properly forwarding it out.

mapview inside of a scrollview seems messy though....